# Windows 8.1 download failure

Tags: windows-8, windows-store, windows-8.1-preview

I have been trying to download the Windows 8.1 Pro Preview since it came out last Wednesday (the 26th), but I've been having several issues.

First and most importantly, no matter how long I leave the download running it never goes past 44%. I have a slow internet connection so I expect large things like that to take a while, but after leaving it for 8 hours it was at 44%. Leaving it overnight did not help and it was still at 44% when I woke up. The Windows store still reports that the update is "Downloading" but not progress is ever made. If I try to pause, then resume the download it starts over from zero.

Second, if the Windows Store lost focus for any reason, the download would switch to "Pending" and never resume downloading. This would happen even if my computer went to sleep, so I started changing the power settings when I was attempting to get the update.

The only solution I can think of is that the update is sitting somewhere on my computer 44% complete and interfering with any attempts to retry the download. That's for my first problem at least. I just assume that the Windows Store being poorly written is the cause of the second problem, though I could more than likely be wrong.

Has anyone run into similar problems, and if so how did you fix them?

Comment: Can you please provide a link of where are downloading this file? And which browser do you use?

Comment: just use bittorrent...

Comment: @matan129 I am downloading the Windows 8.1 Pro Preview from the Windows Store. There is no link or browser.

Comment: I don't quite understand the "no link" thing. Anyways, try downloading from [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/preview-download)(scroll down a bit).

Comment: By no link I mean that I open the Windows app store and click on the large box that says "Update Windows" and "Windows 8.1 preview". I'll try the iso download though. Thank you.

Comment: Try rebooting your router and plug directly into your ethernet.

Comment: @Mr.Zurg Can you try uninstalling and reinstalling the update that prepares the store for the update? I forgot what handled it, but it might be in your Windows Update history

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the ISO from MS page:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/preview-iso

mount the ISO, run the setup.exe and select "upgrade".

Comment: Are you sure this is the same as downloading the update from the store? The language on both pages raises some eyebrows, saying it's either for 8.0 Enterprise users, or "advanced user[s who] want to install the preview on another partition, another PC, or a virtual machine."

Comment: this should also work. The Update also downlaods a huge ESD file which is mostly the same like the ISO.

Comment: Please note the above link is no longer a valid solution the Preview build is expired and not an exceptional source for the RTM build of Windows 8.1